# $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+\exp(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to check, whether  $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+\exp(n)}$ converges or diverge.

I tried to use the comparison test:
$$|\frac{1}{n+\exp(n)}|\leq \frac{1}{\exp(n)} = \frac{1}{\frac{n^n}{n!}} = \frac{n!}{n^n} $$

$\frac{n!}{n^n}$ converge $\Rightarrow$ $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+\exp(n)}$ converge.

Can somebody please tell me, if this is correct?

Comment: Do you think that $\exp(n) = \frac{n^n}{n!}$?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is the definition of $\exp(x)$. So $\exp(n) = \frac{n^n}{n!}$. Can somebody please tell me, if this is correct?

Comment: No, this is not correct. You cannot reuse the index in the sum. $$\exp(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a much easier way. Note that
$$\dfrac1{n+e^n} < \dfrac1{e^n}$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{n+e^n} < \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac1{e^n} = \dfrac{e}{e-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use [Quotient test](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=617931) to see that $$n^{3/2}u_n\to 0<\infty, ~~n\to\infty$$

Comment: It is clear that $u_n=O(n^2)$

Comment: @GabrielR.: So? :)

Comment: I forgot the minus sign $O(n^{-2} )$. I like the bigO notation better,  as everybody :) .

Answer (score 0):

The transition $1/e^n = \frac{n^n}{n!} $ inaccurately and needs some explanation, what you can do instead is use the fact the $a_n=1/e^n$ is geometric sequence.